# Is it possible to make an AutoUpdate feature in any of iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

i need to implement an autoupdate feature in my iPhone app like if i released a version 1.0 then i upgraded it to 1.1 then who ever the users using 1.0 in there devices in background my update has to run.
I know that there is an in-App Purchase, APNS feature but rather than that is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, all updates has to be in the App Store in the first place.
You could "auto-update" your app if your principal frame is loaded directly from the Internet.